# Zenoss modeling localhost

Tags: monitoring, localhost, zenoss

Immediately after installing it, Zenoss appears to try to model the server it's installed on. That's fine, but I only understand how to configure Zenoss to model a server via snmp, ssh, or some other network-bound service. Since ssh/command modeling is essentially interpreting the results of commands run on the system, is there no way to shortcut that process by eliminating the `ssh` part of the step, and simply *run* the command on localhost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modelling is process in which zenoss runs modeller [Under a device
   Left hand side Modeller plugins] plugin against the device, to get
   basic information which wont change frequently for eg: interfaces,
   file-system partition, Os name, etc. Zenoss will remodel the device
   every 12 hours.

So to monitor a device you need to install net-snmp on device with a community string. And need to add the device into zenoss by
   using the 'snmp community name' used in client device. So that every
   300 sec zenoss will go and get perfromance metrics depending on which
   device Class the device is added Eg: /Server/Linux. For The device
   class a monitoring template related to Linux will be applied.

Monitoring Template is nothing but a set of parameter that need to be monitored on the managed device. Eg: Memory, CPU